# iPhone - location services can be disabled

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I have two kids using iPhones with Family Sharing.  In Screen Time under 'Content & Privacy Restriction', the option for **Privacy > Share My Location** is set to **Don't Allow**.  My understanding is that this will prevent them from turning it off under Screen Time on their device or prompt for the passcode I have set.

What I'm also seeing is that under **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Location Services**, is the ability to turn this off which seems to override the previous setting and results in their device not showing in the Find My app.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enable [sharing of location between family members](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201087) and also want to ensure that your kids can't turn it off on their device.

On your kids phone -

**Enable Location Sharing**:

Go to **`Settings` > Privacy > Location Services > Share My Location** and tap on the toggle button to enable sharing the iPhone's location.

**Enable Restriction to Prevent Turning it Off**:

1. In **`Settings` > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Share My Location**, tap "Don't Allow".
2. In **`Settings` > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Location Services**, tap on "Don't Allow Changes".

The first step will lock "*Share My Location*" settings, and prevent it from being changed. The second step will prevent all setting options in "*Location Services*" from  being changed and prevent access to it from *Settings > Privacy > Location Services* too.

(**Note**: If any apps your kids use require "Location" permission, please enable it before restricting access to the *Location Services* options as described in Step 2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this makes more sense now, a confusing layer of near duplicate settings!

Comment: @piagetblix If you are satisfied with the answer you can press the tick (✔️) below the voting arrows. It lets the community and outsiders know that’s the correct answer and serves as a guide for the future.

Comment: My only small caveat, is that the settings 1. and 2. need to happen on the childs phone.  I was fixated on the idea that I should be able to push it from my phone under Family Sharing or Screen Time.  Not the case. Number 2. doesn't even appear in the scren time app.  I gues this is an Apple privacy first intentional configuration.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to highlight that that these settings must be done on your kids phone so there isn't any confusion on this.

Comment: In iOS 16.5 the second setting “Location Services” is no longer available. My kid succeeded in turning off Location Services without our consent permission. Which settings do we need in iOS 16.5?

Comment: @RichardKranendonk Check under Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Privacy ... is Location Services and Share My Location there?

Comment: Nope, not anymore, not in iOS 16.5

Comment: @RichardKranendonk Do you use "Family Sharing"? If yes, check for the option on **your** device: Screen Time > (Family Member) > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Share My Location [Don’t Allow] ...